# MVC and AngularJS routing

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have created an MVC application and added an Angularjs nuget.
It was created HomeController and view for it.
Home controlled isn't changed at all.
My folder hierarchy:

[image]

Index.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/App/App.js"></script>

    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="sampleApp">

    <a href="#/route1">Route 1</a><br />
    <a href="#/route2">Route 2</a><br />

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script>
        var module = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute']);

        module.config(
            function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                    when('/route1', {
                        templateUrl: 'Views/Home.html',
                        controller: 'RouteController'
                    }).
                    when('/route2', {
                        templateUrl: 'Views/Home.html',
                        controller: 'RouteController'
                    }).
                    otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    });
            });

        module.controller("RouteController", function ($scope) {
            alert("I am here");
        })
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Clicking on the links produces an 404 error
`http://localhost:50265/Home/Views/Home.html` - this is link that was generated.
I don't understand why there is **Home** inserted in link.
And as the page of error said that it expected physical path

```
E:\SoftServe\IndividualTask\IndividualTask\Home\Views\Home.html
```

but i don't have **Home** folder in root folder `E:\SoftServe\IndividualTask\IndividualTask`
I set the route to 'Views/Home.html' but not to 'Home/Views/Home.html'.

What is the base path for routing? How to make it work?

Comment: MVC doesn't allow to access files from view folder..you need to manipulate that thing by defining handler in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

> MVC doesn't allow to access files from view folder..you need to
>   manipulate that thing by defining handler in web.config

Thank you. I have found this article: http://forums.asp.net/t/1689087.aspx?ASP+NET+MVC+Using+content+in+Views+folder and replace

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

on

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

in web.config file that allows to get files from the View folder and doesn't allow only *.cshtml files from it.